# If $\mathcal C$ is semiadditive, then $\text{Hom}(a,b)$ in $\mathcal C$ is monoid.

Tags: category-theory

Let $f,g\in\text{Hom}(a,b)$. I want to define $f+g$ and show $f+g=g+f$.

Take $f\times g\in \text{Hom}(a,b\oplus b)$ such that
$$\pi_b^1\circ(f\times g)=f\\\pi_b^2\circ(f\times g)=g$$

Take $\nabla_b\in \text{Hom}(b\oplus b, b)$ such that
$$\nabla_b\circ i_b^1=\nabla_b\circ i_b^2=\text{id}_b$$

Take $\varphi\in\text{Hom}(b\oplus b,b\oplus b) $ such that
$$\varphi\circ i_b^1=i_b^2\\\varphi\circ i_b^2=i_b^1$$

Then, since $(\nabla_b\circ \varphi)\circ i_b^1=(\nabla_b\circ\varphi)\circ i_b^2=\text{id}_b$, $\nabla_b\circ \varphi=\nabla_b$.

Take $\psi\in\text{Hom}(b\oplus b,b\oplus b)$ such that
$$\pi_b^1\circ\psi=\pi_b^2\\\pi_b^2\circ\psi=\pi_b^1$$

Samely, $\psi\circ (f\times g)=g\times f$.

If I could show $\varphi=\psi$, then :

$$
\begin{align}f+g=&\nabla_b\circ (f\times g)\\=&\nabla_b\circ \varphi\circ (f\times g)\\=&\nabla_b\circ \psi\circ (f\times g)\\=&\nabla_b\circ (g\times f)=g+f\end{align}$$

But I don't know how to show $\varphi=\psi$. How do I show this, or is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$I don't understand your notation, or your definition of $f+g$: if you define
$$
A \overset{\Delta_A}\to A\oplus A \overset{f\oplus g}\to B\oplus B \overset{\nabla_B}\to B
$$ this sets up a commutative binary operation simply because the diagram
$$
\begin{CD}
A @>>> A\oplus A @>f\oplus g>> B\oplus B @>>> B \\ 
@|@V\sigma_AVV@VV\sigma_BV@|\\
A @>>> A\oplus A @>>g\oplus f> B\oplus B @>>> B
\end{CD}
$$ is commutative, if the vertical arrows are the symmetry isomorphisms.